# Retrieving data from a countries API

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using an API to get a list of countries in Laravel. I have been able to isolate the countries list only but the countries now have an inner array with details of the country. I only need the name. I've tried using foreach but it didn't work.
This below is the result from the api

```
#items: array:2 [▼
"countries" => array:198 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "code" => "BT"
    "name" => "Bhutan"
    "geonameid" => 1252634
    "depends_on" => null
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
```

This below is the code fetching it

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
        'x-rapidapi-host' => 'world-geo-data.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key' => '1fa601995fmshcc1d2fcc97ee24cp1ac29djsn9b9b11cc10ec',
        //'x-rapidapi-key' => config('app.rapid_api_key'),
    ])->get('https://world-geo-data.p.rapidapi.com/countries');
    
    //dd($response->collect());
    
    return $response->collect()->pluck('name')
    ->all();
```

I'm trying to get only the name value. the return is returning null

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: @IrshadKhan code shared

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
return collect($response->collect()["countries"])->pluck('name');
```

The result will be like:

[image: This will be the result]

Comment: Exactly! Thank. you